# Symfony validation component multi dimensional form data

Tags: symfony, validation

I have a form that has fields that allow you to add multiple user information by clicking add another user button.

At the server side I want to validate all first names and last names as required.

My problem is I have no idea how to validate repeating data like fname and lname is here.

```
$stripToken = $request->request->get('stripeToken');

        $input = $request->request->all();
        var_dump($input);
        try {
            $constraint = new Assert\Collection(array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'guest_fname' => new Assert\All(array(
                        'constraints' => array(
                            new Assert\NotBlank(),
                            new Assert\MinLength(array('limit' => 2))
                        )
                    )),
                    'guest_lname' => new Assert\All(array(
                        'constraints' => array(
                            new Assert\NotBlank(),
                            new Assert\MinLength(array('limit' => 2))
                        )
                    ))
                ),
                'allowMissingFields' => true,
            ));
        }catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }

        $errors = $this->app['validator']->validate($input, $constraint);
```

This code is not working.The var_dump of input returns

```
array(6) {
  ["guest_fname"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "asdd"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "asdasd"
    [2]=>
    string(9) "asdasdasd"
  }
  ["guest_lname"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "asdasd"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "asdasd"
    [2]=>
    string(9) "asdasdasd"
  }
  ["guest_email"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  ["guest_phone"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  ["guest_count"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["stripeToken"]=>
  string(28) "tok_234234234234234"
}
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant parts of your *FormType (the part where you actually add the fields to the form-builder) to the question please?

Comment: @nifr I have updated the question. I am not using FormType.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the newer version of the component's assert option list does not have MinLength option. Instead the option is Length. Here's the constraint code that fixes this.

```
$constraint = new Assert\Collection(array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'guest_fname' => new Assert\All(array(
                        'constraints' => array(
                            new Assert\NotBlank(),
                            new Assert\Length(array(
                                'min'   => 3,
                                'minMessage' => 'Your name must have at least {{ limit }} characters.',
                            ))
                        )
                    )),
                    'guest_lname' => new Assert\All(array(
                        'constraints' => array(
                            new Assert\NotBlank(),
                            new Assert\Length(array(
                                'min'   => 3,
                                'minMessage' => 'Your name must have at least {{ limit }} characters.',
                            ))
                        )
                    ))
                ),
                'allowMissingFields' => true
            ));
```

The rest of the code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You're wrapping `Assert\All()` inside `Assert\Collection()` while `Assert\All()` would be enough in your case.

Your `$input` is **not** a collection (iterable) but an array with key/value pairs. Just validate each key on it's own.

```
$constraint = new Assert\All(array(
    'constraints' => array(
        new Assert\NotBlank(),
        new Assert\Length(array('min' => 5)),
    ),
);
$errors = $this->app['validator']->validate($input['guest_fname'], $constraint);
```

... or you *could* wrap `$input` with an iterable (i.e. array) when passing it to the validator and keep using your wrapping `Assert\Collection()`:

```
$errors = $this->app['validator']->validate(array($input), $constraint);
```